# Job seeking in USA with ESTA

Tags: visas, usa, esta

Despite the fact that the following matter has been brought up several times already, I would like to have confirmation as it is not so clear.

My situation is the following: I am looking for openings in the USA from Italy, by sending e-mails, resume and cover letters, etc., but in a couple of weeks I am going to the USA for about a month to spend the holidays there and meet with some friends from college. Then I've thought to continue my job search in the USA itself without the intention to remain and start working (which I am totally aware is illegal), but only to try to schedule job interviews face to face, because I believe that this might be a better chance both to obtain a work visa and to point myself out.

Is this all illegal too as it seems to be, or is job seeking in the USA (without the intention to remain illegally but only to try to have a sponsor) legal?

Comment: If the linked duplicate does not answer your question, please edit your question or respond to this comment to explain why.